# To see email tracking information in GA from MC

Tags: marketing-cloud, google-analytics, email-tracking

Maybe a bit weird question, but is that possible to use utm parameters in MC on email sends so that it's possible to see the tracking data in GA without actually setting up a Connector?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2020_google_integration_parameter_manager.htm&type=5

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to configure Parameter Manager as described in [these docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_parameter_management.htm&type=5). The default string which will be automatically appended to all the links is:

```
utm_source=sfmc​&utm_medium=email​&utm_campaign=%%emailname_%%​&utm_term=%%linkname%%​&utm_id=%%jobid%%​&sfmc_id=%%subscriberid%%
```

You can use majority of the personalisation strings available in Email Studio, to ensure the parameters follow your tagging conventions.

I will also recommend you to have a look at Additional Email Attributes, [as described here.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000353527&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1) These will allow you to append up to 5 email specific strings, which you populate when creating the email.